# Using third party UI component as angularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, github, npm, angularjs-directive, drag-and-drop

There is a npm package named smooth-dnd. This is it's github repo : 
https://github.com/kutlugsahin/smooth-dnd#readme
The package can be installed in react, angular and vue.js. However my project is in angularjs. I am new to such kind of problem, so any suggestion on how should I add this npm package to my angularjs project by creating a directive of my own.

Comment: to check the npm package is installed check the package.json file in your project. Package.json shows all the dependencies that you had installed. To use smooth-dnd firstly install it and create a div tag assign id then call that id in .ts file. Github repo that you mentioned shows how to use it.

Comment: @AwareFun yes but I cannot install it as my project is in angularjs. I have to create a directive and inside that fill the appropriate code of the github repo. How should I figure that out as the repo is quite big.

Comment: In github repo they had  npm module for angular. https://github.com/kutlugsahin/ngx-smooth-dnd/

Comment: @AwareFun yes but I want for angularjs not angular

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use this library specifically, but rather need to implement the drag-n-drop functionality, I'd recommend [andular-drag-n-drop-lists](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested) which already has angularjs wrapper.

I used it in one of my projects, worked like a charm.

The usage is simple:

```
<ul class="b-statuses-list" dnd-list="vm.leadStatusList">
    <li class="b-unit-status -type_draggable"
    ng-repeat="status in vm.leadStatusList"
    dnd-moved="vm.leadStatusList.splice($index, 1)"
    dnd-dragend="vm.onUpdateOrderLeadStatus()"
    dnd-draggable="status"
    dnd-effect-allowed="move">
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```